# Plantilla Bootstrap no detecta la ruta de imágenes o estilos

Tags: html5, bootstrap, codeigniter

Buenos días tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo una plantilla Bootstrap entonces cuando la corro se muestra correctamente, pero lo que necesito hacer es pasar esa plantilla al framework de CodeIgniter entonces cambien él .html por .php y tengo los siguientes niveles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la carpeta plantillas tendré varias plantillas, después tengo el directorio 1 donde tengo mi primera plantilla que es index.php, allí mismo tengo el directorio elementos donde tengo los directorios de images y revolution, en revolution tengo el directorio css entonces llamo a todos los elementos de la plantilla y no se están aplicando, solo me aparece el puro texto de la plantilla sin estilos y sin nada.

Este es un ejemplo de cómo estoy llamando a mis elementos pero no los está aplicando.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="elementos/revolution/css/settings.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="elementos/revolution/css/layers.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="elementos/revolution/css/navigation.css">
```

Alguien sabe porque no los esta aplicando?

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Si dentro de la carpeta elementos tienes el **index.php** y la carpeta **revolution/css** puedes dejar tu href así : `revolution/css/nombredeestilos.css`

Comment: dentro de la carpeta 1 tengo a index.php y alli esta la carpeta elementos

Comment: y elementos tengo a images y revolution

Comment: Entonces es por tu editor de código, me pareció ver que tu **index.php** está dentro de la carpeta elementos  y no dentro de la carpeta 1

Comment: No es eso, esta bien el editor de codigo

Comment: Según la imagen, el index está dentro de elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Como te han dicho en los comentarios tu index.php está dentro de la carpeta de elementos, por lo que tu enlace estaría mal. O sacas tu index.php de la carpeta elementos y dejas tu código como está; o no mueves tu archivo y cambias la ruta de tus estilos para que queden de esta forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="revolution/css/settings.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="revolution/css/layers.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="revolution/css/navigation.css">
```